# How do i limit the count/sum of a column to 3 per month?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, pandas-groupby, python-datetime

I have this dataset df,

```
ID    Name
23    Dan
24    Bob
```

This dataset shows relationship of each ID

```
ID    ID2       DATE       Status
23    10     2019-06-11     Sent
23    20     2019-06-21     Sent
23    30     2019-06-26     Sent
23    40     2019-06-27     Sent
23    50     2019-12-02     Sent
24    55     2019-06-27     Sent
24    65     2019-06-29     Sent
```

Here, ID 23 sent letters to ID's 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 on the mentioned DATE. I wanted to get the count of how many each ID sent letters to. 
I did something like this,

```
id = df.groupby(['ID'], as_index = False)
id_dict = {}

all_df = id.get_group(ID)

letter_count = 0
for index, row in all_df.iterrows():
        if ((row['Status'] == 'Sent')):
            letter_count = letter_count + 1

id_dict.update({ID:letter_count})
df['letter_count'] = df['ID'].map(id_dict)
```

I get this output on df,

```
ID    Name  letter_count
23    Dan        4
24    Bob        2
```

DATE is not taken into consideration. I might need a new column MONTH and even YEAR.
I need to have the count of letters sent set to 3 per month. Here, for the month of June 4 letters were sent but i need the count to stay at 3 for every month. This number should be configurable.

Required new output:

```
ID    Name  Month   Year   letter_count
23    Dan    06     2019         3
23    Dan    12     2019         1
24    Bob    06     2019         2
```

Comment: Do you want like quarterly count of sent email? Like `2019/Jan-March, 2019/Apr-Jun,...`?

Comment: @aishwaryaprabhu I'm confused as to what you're asking for here. Can you provide an example output of what you're expecting?

Comment: @QuangHoang No....ID 23 should be able to send only 3 letters per month. The count should not increase for the 4th one. Max per month is 3

Comment: You mean you want the `letter_count` to show `3` even though it's `4`? Or, if you're talking about limiting the input to be `3` per `ID` then that needs to happen *waaaay* before it gets to your `df`..., in which case, the relevant code is not shown, and we have no idea where the data is coming from.

Comment: @Andy I have updated the question. Also put an required output. I assume thats the best output but open for new approaches

Comment: @r.ook Yes. I want the letter_count to show 3 even if it's 4 because of the LIMIT. I have updated my question. Please do have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply [`clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html) after doing a `groupby` to keep the count at `3`:

```
# Add Year/Month and check if Sent columns
df['DATE'] = df.DATE.astype('datetime64')
df.assign(Year=df.DATE.dt.strftime('%Y'), \
          Month=df.DATE.dt.strftime('%m'), \
          Sent=df['Status'].eq('Sent'))

# Your data should look like this at this point:    

   ID  ID2       DATE Status  Year Month  Sent
0  23   10 2019-06-11   Sent  2019    06  True
1  23   20 2019-06-21   Sent  2019    06  True
2  23   30 2019-06-26   Sent  2019    06  True
3  23   40 2019-06-27   Sent  2019    06  True
4  23   50 2019-12-02   Sent  2019    12  True
5  24   55 2019-06-27   Sent  2019    06  True
6  24   65 2019-06-29   Sent  2019    06  True

# Apply the groupby and clip:
new_df = df.groupby(['ID', 'Year', 'Month'])['Sent'].count().clip(upper=3).reset_index()

# Merge back the names:
new_df = new_df.merge(df_name, how='left')

# Which gives you:
   ID  Year Month  Sent Name
0  23  2019    06     3  Dan
1  23  2019    12     1  Dan
2  24  2019    06     2  Bob
```

I still wonder if this answers the true purpose of this exercise though.  At the end of the day, you're just lying to yourself in the summarized frame.

Answer (score 0):

Groupy by `ID` and get the total count per ID. Then if the `count > 4`, set it to `3`.

```
df2 = df.groupby(['ID']).agg({'ID2': count})
df2['ID2'] = np.where(df2['ID2] > 3, 3, df2['ID2'])
```

Comment: Can we do np.where but with groupby for Month?
Like, if count > 3 for a particular month?